# export java methods to react native from an aar library

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, sdk

I'm trying to integrate a SDK in my react native app, and i'm little bit confused, as documentation says, i know that i have to write a bridge in order to use the native library in react native.
here is what i've done:

1. I put the sdk-file.aar in android/app/libs.
2. I created libraryModule.java and libraryPackage.java

with the folowing code

libraryModule.java

```
package com.myapp.android;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.ekassir.mirpaysdk.client.MirApp;


public class MirPayModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

MirPayModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "MirPaySdk";
}
@ReactMethod
    {
        
    }
}. // I think some methods should be here
```

My question is: should i recreate all methods present in the library ?
I'm receiving the sdk from a bank, should i recreate all methods with @ReactMethod tag in order to have the possibility to access them in react native ?
Am i missing something in the process of integration ?